# Java HashMap: Changing Bucket Implementation to Linear Probing method

Tags: java, hashmap

In advance, I apologize for my lack of experience, these are advanced concepts that are difficult to wrap my head around. From what I understand, linear probing is circular, it won't stop until it finds an empty cell.

However I am not sure how to implement it. Some example on how to would be greatly appreciated. Sorry again for the inexperience, I'm not some vetted programmer, I'm picking this up very slowly.

```
 public boolean ContainsElement(V element)
   {
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] != null)
        {
            LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> bucketMethod = table[i];
            for(Entry<K, V> entry : bucketMethod)
            {
                if(entry.getElement().equals(element))
                {
                    return true;
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      return false;
   }
```

Comment: There's an example of this on the Wikipedia page for open addressing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing

Comment: If you had a moment, would you be able to demonstrate how my java code should look edited with the open addressing pseudo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working hash table based on the pseudocode examples found in the [Wikipedia article for open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing).

I think the main differences between the Wikipedia example and mine are:

- Treating the `hashCode()` a little bit due to the way Java does modulo (`%`) with negative numbers.
- Implemented simple resizing logic.
- Changed the logic in the `remove` method a little bit because Java doesn't have `goto`.

Otherwise, it's more or less just a direct translation.

```
package mcve;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class OAHashTable {
    private Entry[] table = new Entry[16]; // Must be >= 4. See findSlot.
    private int     size  = 0;

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    private int hash(Object key) {
        int hashCode = Objects.hashCode(key)
            & 0x7F_FF_FF_FF; // <- This is like abs, but it works
                             //    for Integer.MIN_VALUE. We do this
                             //    so that hash(key) % table.length
                             //    is never negative.
        return hashCode;
    }

    private int findSlot(Object key) {
        int i = hash(key) % table.length;

        // Search until we either find the key, or find an empty slot.
        //
        // Note: this becomes an infinite loop if the key is not already
        //       in the table AND every element in the array is occupied.
        //       With the resizing logic (below), this will only happen
        //       if the table is smaller than length=4.
        while ((table[i] != null) && !Objects.equals(table[i].key, key)) {
            i = (i + 1) % table.length;
        }

        return i;
    }

    public Object get(Object key) {
        int i = findSlot(key);
        if (table[i] != null) { // Key is in table.
            return table[i].value;
        } else {                // Key is not in table
            return null;
        }
    }

    private boolean tableIsThreeQuartersFull() {
        return ((double) size / (double) table.length) >= 0.75;
    }

    private void resizeTableToTwiceAsLarge() {
        Entry[] old = table;

        table = new Entry[2 * old.length];
        size  = 0;

        for (Entry e : old) {
            if (e != null) {
                put(e.key, e.value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void put(Object key, Object value) {
        int i = findSlot(key);
        if (table[i] != null) { // We found our key.
            table[i].value = value;
            return;
        }
        if (tableIsThreeQuartersFull()) {
            resizeTableToTwiceAsLarge();
            i = findSlot(key);
        }
        table[i] = new Entry(key, value);
        ++size;
    }

    public void remove(Object key) {
        int i = findSlot(key);
        if (table[i] == null) {
            return; // Key is not in the table.
        }

        int j = i;
        table[i] = null;
        --size;

        while (true) {
            j = (j + 1) % table.length;
            if (table[j] == null) {
                break;
            }
            int k = hash(table[j].key) % table.length;
            // Determine if k lies cyclically in (i,j]
            // |    i.k.j |
            // |....j i.k.| or  |.k..j i...|
            if ( (i<=j) ? ((i<k)&&(k<=j)) : ((i<k)||(k<=j)) ) {
                continue;
            }
            table[i] = table[j];
            i = j;
            table[i] = null;
        }
    }

    public Stream<Entry> entries() {
        return Arrays.stream(table).filter(Objects::nonNull);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return entries().map(e -> e.key + "=" + e.value)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
    }

    public static class Entry {
        private Object key;
        private Object value;

        private Entry(Object key, Object value) {
            this.key   = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Object getKey()   { return key;   }
        public Object getValue() { return value; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OAHashTable t = new OAHashTable();

        t.put("A", 1);
        t.put("B", 2);
        t.put("C", 3);

        System.out.println("size = " + t.size());
        System.out.println(t);

        t.put("X", 4);
        t.put("Y", 5);
        t.put("Z", 6);
        t.remove("C");
        t.remove("B");
        t.remove("A");

        t.entries().map(e -> e.key)
                   .map(key -> key + ": " + t.get(key))
                   .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

java.util.HashMap implementation of java.util.Map internally provides linear probing that is HashMap can resolve collisions in hash tables.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `java.util.HashMap` uses separate chaining with either a linked list or tree. Linear probing is a search algorithm used for open addressing. See for example http://www.cs.rmit.edu.au/online/blackboard/chapter/05/documents/contribute/chapter/05/linear-probing.html.